# Trying to make check box mute music

Tags: android, checkbox, android-studio, onclick, mute

I'm confused on how to make the check box mute the media player. FYI I am learning about dialog boxes, buttons, checkboxes now. I just recently learned how to add music so any help is appreciated!

```
public class DialogBox extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    MediaPlayer mySound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_box);

        Button one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        one.setOnClickListener(this);
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mario);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btn:
              mySound.start();
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First step to add your checkbox to your activity's layout.

```
<CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/checkbox_mute"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Mute" />
```

Second step to create your checkbox object (inside onCreate()) and set a click listener to it.

```
Checkbox muteCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_mute);
muteCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(muteCheckBox .isChecked()){
                // mediaplayer is already muted, so needs be to unmuted
                mySound.setVolume(1,1);
            }else{
                // mute media player
                mySound.setVolume(0,0);
            }
        }
    });
```